# SQL Server Calculation Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please I was trying to get this correct. Am I doing wrong here.
I get a percentage based on amount. But when I try to get the amount from percentage it is not correct.

```
SELECT (1000 / 1271.11) * 100
```

I get 78.6713900

But when I multiply I get

```
SELECT 1271.11 * 0.786713900
```

I get 999.99990542900  it should be 1000

Any clue on this.
Thanks

Comment: Floating point number are inherently imprecise - please read [what ever programmer should know about floating point](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: @SMor They are not inherenly imprecise, they are precise for anything of a power of 2 (base 2). They cannot inherently encode every possible decimal (base 10) fraction. The reason that SQL Server calls them imprecise is because different processors implement them internally slightly differently (128-bit or 80-bit or 64-bit) so the results are not always guaranteed

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that dividing by `anything.11` requires too many decimal places to be reversed easily (you can see that `SELECT 1000.00000000 / 1271.1100000000;` gets you a number that's closer, [but still no cigar](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e0b2cacff5dd766ed8180e2b6edd8cc)). Much simpler to use `CEILING` (or `ROUND`):

```
SELECT CEILING(1271.11 * 0.786713900);
```

Result:

```
1000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get back 1000 you can use the function `ROUND()`. The difference is at the 10th place after the point so you'd have to be in a very specialised application for it to make any difference.

```
<!-- -->
>     declare @var float(38);
>     set @var =(1000.000 / 1271.11);
>     select 1271.11*@var, @var;
>     select round(1271.11*@var,9);
>     select round(1271.11*@var,10);

>     GO
> 
> <pre>
> (No column name) | (No column name)
> ---------------: | ---------------:
> 999.999999999584 |     0.7867139744
> 
> | (No column name) |
> | ---------------: |
> |             1000 |
> 
> | (No column name) |
> | ---------------: |
> |   999.9999999996 |
> </pre>

<!-- -->
>     declare @var decimal(20,10);
>     set @var =(1000.000 / 1271.11);
>     select 1271.11*@var, @var;
>     select round(1271.11*@var,9);
>     select round(1271.11*@var,10);

>     GO
> 
> <pre>
> (No column name) | (No column name)
> ---------------: | ---------------:
> 999.999999999584 |     0.7867139744
> 
> |  (No column name) |
> | ----------------: |
> | 1000.000000000000 |
> 
> | (No column name) |
> | ---------------: |
> | 999.999999999600 |
> </pre>

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6e1baa4da39f97b8acbf028cdf452039)*
```